# RISCV function using registers

Tags: assembly, riscv

What is the returning value of this code using RISCV
consider c the form is  `int fun(int n)`

```
fun: 
addi s0, zero, 0 
addi s1, zero, 1 
add t0, zero, a0
loop: 
beq s0, t0, exit 
add s1, s1, s1 
addi s0, s0, 1 
jal zero, loop 
exit: 
add a0, zero, s1 
jalr zero, 0(ra)
```

Comment: Step through the code in a debugger (or using pen and paper) for some small values of `n` (e.g. 1, 2 and 3) and see what happens.

Comment: I think return n right?

Comment: No, that doesn't sound quite right. You need to go through the code again and look more closely at what each instruction does.

Comment: I just new with assembly may you please explain it ?

Comment: @YassenGamal You're expected to put in work when you ask a question here, not just expect an answer to a problem. Do you know what each of these instructions do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, when analysing assembly, it can be helpful to directly what's happening as C, then simplifying:

```c
int fun(int n) {
    int s0 = 0;
    int s1 = 1;
    int t0 = n; // n is in a0

loop:
    if (s0 == t0) {
        goto loop_exit;
    }

    s1 = s1 + s1;
    s0 = s0 + 1;

    goto loop;

loop_exit:
    return s1; // Returns in a0
}
```

We can see that copying to `t0` isn't needed, we can use `n` directly. Also, this `goto` construct looks a lot like a `while` loop, with the condition check for looping at the beginning.

```c
int fun(int n) {
    int s0 = 0;
    int s1 = 1;

    while (s0 != n) {
        s1 += s1;
        s0 += 1;
    }

    return s1;
}
```

We can now see that `s1` will start at 1, then be doubled `n` times. We can rewrite giving descriptive names, and substituting the `while` for a `for`:

```c
int fun(int n) {
    int value = 1;

    for (int counter = 0; counter != n; counter += 1) {
        value += value;
    }

    return value;
}
```

Thanks to the beauty of compilers, these three sets of code [actually generate](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qgA%2BhOSkAzpnbICeOpUy10AYVSsArgFtag1egAyeWpgByegEaZiXAJykADqmmEltTTv2DX7xTpTcytdW3tOJ1l5QNoGAmZiAm89A04ZOUwFT3jEgmDLGztHGQSklN906TL8s0Kw4siAShlUbWJkDgByMwIAaiptWghevtomvoBSAHYAIUmABgBBPtW%2B0ekFqYBmABE%2Bhcnt%2BeW19fo%2B6U4d/c4jk5W10YIto/3ae76Aei%2Bx9elzn1mIdloslqxUKhnCAwWc8FQ%2BhBNjc3n0XhMZg8zmdgKgiH0IVCxJgAB6Ee6wtYzXZgymrK43S7XSYAJlmTIppzWyNRPLZfTux1pXNWuPxhOcnKWYIlxLJBBhIr6xEwBHatA5x2%2BvwASqr1QCzECQdLpjTll0WqwQF0AKxdUgGLoLB2oG3qS5tDqYKYs7acB0K52WloAay40wAdNwHNsABzTFm2mMLSIANk40yENu4DqdLtIbq6DukIAWpCDLpacFgSDQumceHYZAoEHrjebIGIADdtizkMhhKJSFQmwQ7KWINYbQXrGZEgBPG0B0j13SqAgAeVorCXwdIWF0ImA7BnDvwKuy3cwpf3pKy2nHy4dvTkZ6EeGsxEXmiwz4rxB4Loz4tDQ9BMGwHA8PwIAskIx4gBIYhSKwn6lpALRQrEt4ALSbiyfQ4QA6mwrCEURpIEN%2BJaZNkygQEYFRpKQRgFKE4R%2BG4Hh0ExnEBJ4bFFBEGQxDkNS8VUtGxLkSSCQ0wnVHkEmlHkckcZwLTSF6nRcFaNr2o675FjqACSDDqDhABqyq9iywDIH0g7HoiVFDKGEwQLghAkL6/qkH0mgNk2di%2BSyEzqIGZ5NGGXC2pGcbbA43Bpgs0xxtw/rbNMfnWl0uaGfuRYlmWFZRaQNaICgGA4PgRAtpQYGMCwp7QQIcFDuIkgiVksQqGoymsXU7GNHB/jcV4WipHx41qSN3V0XE4mTZU83STUs0RHBinlMtzHbbUIRCVwYWtO0Ok9BcgzDKM4xTHMdLnP0PJ7AcUpwhcDKooKDwPQA7ggwWIsiYBgKit2Yg9ZwMgAVKiLJvdi9KvGyX0I6s1LCo8qwqmqxAalcUoYxael2nmRnup6Z0%2BqyfaRcG0WkOGnBppGaZs%2BzHPs1muX5fmro2sV5aVpa5UwJV7bBfVbaoEFnY9n2A4dSOY4TpQ077nOtCLv%2Ba4btuu7voex6nvuF49Xg163gW97II%2B3Qrq%2BuUFqhX4/tV/5UUBIEjnQTWQVwvACOkHWIV1LvoRAmHONhNp4QRxGkeRlHUatnh9Rou2GGoG3TbEyljbEOeSaJdAyckmfF%2BbpfrUNR1VEtPh7TXh3ybpp3erBJMGXzhY2qZ5lWTZfb2Y5HUucQbkeV5dWhf5gUdiFNMaQFdNVjFzOs5zW9ptzOZk4VAsyCVwvVmLEB1tV08kOQDW%2BxBLWByA2zwaIofIan9GMRXLHZ7XrecOWAunh85cULn/dS5ZohV0Wkpb%2BUCFplyLpAhuU166qXAY0BYmltLdFGFdEYFxwb3SVKMbsbBtDUxet9TGZwaDEERKMNAQxxz0NRIcLUTD6AhRBmDT4nCWG%2BnmFQjExCsbYjIToamKMXoSIoWjO65ppRKhxuqPosjMCEzNGCEWuVu7ky6B6LSVNfLbFXiGRmXAWbby3rvPK%2B8CxFSPkLMqFVz5VVlnYG%2B0sPH2Hlv2Jyw5RysBYZOdWs55zED3CuXW9B9Z7gLEbUQJsEl4EvIoS274bZ23/I7d8LtvyRN/PbQMgFgJdADKBO%2BzUoKP2fiHJCKE0LwCjjHLocdyKJ2IsnZgNES4GAYv1b%2Bg0W7qRcKA4B38gFBAwQpKSYlYGN0EPAta6CRmNBUjtRZaDZIzLbkYju2wu72P5l0fuFlrJ%2BJHgE4A49J6Iivqwv0z8AoywXo87YhyV6lXpuvKx1jOa8B5sc3uxYnHfLXtmLoLJgWOJPi0a8xB3DKG4EAA%3D%3D%3D) the same assembly (on that specific compiler, at the time I write this).

---

When `n` is less than the precision of `int`, this function behaves as a left-shift of 1 by `n` bits.

In this non-edge case, `fun` is equivalent to:

```c
int fun(int n) {
    return 1 << n;
}
```

If `n` is at least the precision of `int`, then you encounter signed integer overflow, which leads to implementation-defined behaviour.